# IIS Rewrite Rule Interferes with $.post to php query

Tags: php, jquery, url-rewrite-module

Running into an issue when calling $.post from jquery while a user is logged in via the facebook js sdk. The response in the callback function is the current page html instead of what is echo'd in the php file. When a user logs in as a non-facebook user, everything works correctly. I can't seem to find any documentation on this issue and feel like i've followed the facebook documentation correctly, but am obviously missing something.

My process is as follows: 1.) user logs in (either via facebook or to my site directly). 2.) user clicks a save link to save a business to their profile. 3.) save link uses jquery to run $.post request to php file to update database. 4.) php returns "1" for success or "0" for failure. 5.) jquery alerts user of failure or deactivates the button on success.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />

  <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/pagejs.js"></script>
  <!-- end scripts -->

  <title><? echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=999999999999999";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <header>
  ... page html...
  <a href='javascript:saveBiz(64)' class='grey-button' title='Save business and add it to your profile.' id='save64'><img src='images/save-small.png' alt='' width='10' height='10' />Save</a>
  ... rest of page ...
```

pagejs.js

```
$(function() {
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
   $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', function(){
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({
          appId: '999999999999999',
          channelUrl: '//www.domain.com/channel.html',
          status: true,
          cookie: true,
          xfnml: true
       });       
       $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
       FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback);
     };
   });
});

function saveBiz(bizID) {
  submitAction = "save";
  $.post("updates.php", { businessID : bizID, action: submitAction },       
    function(responseData){
      if(responseData == "0"){
        alert('An error occurred while saving the business. Please try again. If the problem persists, please contact us.');
      }
      else {
        alert(responseData); // for testing purposes
        $('#save'+bizID).fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href");
        $('#save'+bizID).text('Saved');
        $('#save'+bizID).attr('title','Business saved.');
      }
    },
    "text"
  );
}
```

updates.php

```
<?php
  require_once 'includes/classes/customer.class.php';
  session_start();

  $custID = $_SESSION['customerID'];
  $action = $_POST['action'];
  $bizID = $_POST['businessID'];

  $returnVal= '0';

  if($custID && $bizID && $action == 'save') {
     $returnVal = customers::saveUserBusiness($custID, $bizID);
  }
  elseif($custID && $bizID && $action == 'remove') {
    $returnVal = customers::removeUserBusiness($custID, $bizID);
  }

  echo $returnVal;
?>
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance. Please let me know if there is something missing from the above to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Turns out I mis-diagnosed the issue. After further research, i found that my web.config was the culprit. I am performing a couple of rewrite rules which, according to the browser, changed the path of the updates.php file from www.domain.com\updates.php to www.domain.com\path1\path2\updates.php so the server couldn't find it.

In the $.post request, I changed the path of updates.php from relative to absolute (updates.php to http://www.domain.com/updates.php). Now all is good, except for the day and half I wasted looking for a solution ;)